# Setting an action from an event-listener on a separate HTML page (setting dropdown value from a click event on a separate HTML page)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, event-handling

I have a website with a two html pages.  On the landing page, I have bootstraps "cards" which are basically acting like buttons.  If you click on one, it'll link you to the second page.

Here's one of the clickable "cards":

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="arrest-data">
    <div class="box-part text-center"> <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-handcuffs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="title">
            <h3>Data Examples 1</h3>
        </div>
   <div class="text"> <span>Crime data and other crime statistics</span> </div> <a href="#" class="get-data">GET DATA</a>
</div>
```

On a separate page, I have a filterable table, with dropdowns to filter different categories:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row dropdowns">
  <div class="col-4">
    <select id="categoryDropdown">
      <option value="All">All Topics</option>
      <option value="Category: Arrest Data">Arrest Data</option>
      <option value="Category: Use of Force">Use of Force</option>
      <option value="Category: Human Trafficking">Human Trafficking</option>
      <option value="Category: Treatment and Diversion">Treatment and Diversion</option>
      <option value="Category: Drug and Overdose Data">Drug and Overdose Data</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <select id="formatDropdown">
      <option value="All">All Formats</option>
      <option value="Format: Dashboard">Dashboard</option>
      <option value="Format: PDF">PDF</option>
      <option value="Format: Data Story">Data Story</option>
      <option value="Format: CSV">CSV</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <select id="associateStatusDropdown">
      <option value="All"> All Users </option>
      <option value="Yes">Active Users</option>
      <option value="No">Inactive Users</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> SL.NO </th>
      <th> Data </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="download-forms-table-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> 
        <div class="project-title">
        Criminal Arrest Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-description">
            <p>Example Arrest Data blah blah.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-category">
            <b>Category</b>: Arrest Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-format">
            <b>Format</b>: Dashboard
        </div>
        <div class="project-last-update">
            <b>Last Updated</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
        <div class="project-associated-data">
            <b>Associated Data</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> 
        <div class="project-title">
        Demographics of Arrest Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-description">
            <p>Example Arrest Data Demographics blah blah.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-category">
            <b>Category</b>: Arrest Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-format">
            <b>Format</b>: PDF
        </div>
        <div class="project-last-update">
            <b>Last Updated</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
        <div class="project-associated-data">
            <b>Associated Data</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 3 </td>
      <td> 
        <div class="project-title">
        Drug Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-description">
            <p>Example Drug Data blah blah.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-category">
            <b>Category</b>: Drug Data
        </div>
        <div class="project-format">
            <b>Format</b>: PDF
        </div>
        <div class="project-last-update">
            <b>Last Updated</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
        <div class="project-associated-data">
            <b>Associated Data</b>: 5/16/2022
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's my JavaScript for filtering the table using the dropdowns:

```
$('.container').on("change", 'select', function() {
    console.log("changin")
  var category = $('#categoryDropdown').val().toLowerCase(),
    format = $('#formatDropdown').val().toLowerCase(),
    associate = $('#associateStatusDropdown').val().toLowerCase();

  var table = $("#download-forms-table-tbody");
  var trs = table.find('tr');
  trs.hide();

  var filtered = trs.filter(function(index, elem) {
    var tds_category = $(elem).find('td > div:nth-of-type(3)'); //get the category
    var tds_format = $(elem).find('td > div:nth-of-type(4)'); //get the format
    var all_tds = $(elem).find('td'); //get all td
    //console.log(tds.text())
    console.log(tds_format.text())
    //console.log(tds.eq(1).innerHTML)
    if (category !== "all" && tds_category.text().trim().toLowerCase() !== category) {
      return false;
    }
    if (format !== "all" && tds_format.text().trim().toLowerCase() !== format) {
      return false;
    }
    if (associate !== "all" && all_tds.eq(3).text().trim().toLowerCase() !== associate) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })

  filtered.show();

  if (filtered.length == 0) {
    alert("No Records Found!!!");
  }

});
```

When the user clicks on a card on the first HTML page, I want that event to set the dropdown filter to a certain value.  In this example, when the user clicks on the card, I want the dropdown to be set to `value="Category: Arrest Data"`.

I've tried:

```
$('#arrest-data').click(function(){
    $('#categoryDropdown').val('Category: Arrest Data');
})
```

But no luck.

What is best practice for having an event listener on one HTML page do an action on a different HTML page, like in this scenario?  I believe this involves setting a variable in `localStorage`.

Comment: `$('#arrest-data').click(function(){ localStorage.setItem("category",'Arrest Data'); location="page2.html";
})` perhaps?

Comment: Why not use something like passing search parameters to the second page? And then using JS to select the item based on that search parameter... parameter like `?category=arrestdata`

Comment: Hmm, yes it seems like localstorage is needed.  Can anyone post an answer that might work?  thanks..

Comment: I solved this; I found this answer useful to my use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031447/how-to-change-from-page-2-html-the-option-from-dropdown-menu-with-onclick-functi